# Javascript toggle variable when key "c" pressed

Tags: javascript, html, css, variables, frontend

I'm wondering how using only javascript I can toggle a variable called x if the key "c" is being pressed. What I want to happen is when the key "c" is pressed, the variable will change from 0 to 1 and when the key "c" is lifted, it will revert back to 0. How can this be done? I've already declared the variable and named it x.

```
let x = 0;
```

Comment: [document keydown/keyup events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add two event listeners on the `document`, one for *keydown*, the other for *keyup*.

Note that `keydown` will fire repeatedly so when you toggle `x` to `1`, you should remove the event listener to avoid this. The listener can be re-added when `x` is toggled back to `0`.

```js
let x = 0

const toggle = ({ code, type }) => {
  if (code === "KeyC") { // check for the "c" key
    x ^= 1 // toggle `x`
    
    console.log(type, "set x to", x)
    
    return true // return a flag so we know when x is modified
  }
}

const keydownHandler = e => {
  if (toggle(e)) {
    // remove the event listener to avoid repeats
    document.removeEventListener("keydown", keydownHandler)
  }
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", keydownHandler)

document.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  if (toggle(e)) {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", keydownHandler)
  }
})
```